# spyder mysql connector python

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, mysql-connector, spyder, mysql-connector-python

I am having trouble with mysql-connector for python 2.7 while using the Anaconda Spyder IDE. Although the code below works in Python Gui, i get the following error in spyder: 'ImportError: No Module named mysql.connector'.

Here is the code:

```
import mysql.connector
conn=mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='xxxxx',host='localhost',database='xxxxx')
mycursor=conn.cursor()

mycursor.execute("""SELECT Ir FROM FinProg where ProgCatId = 4""")
obrrate = mycursor.fetchall().
```

I downloaded mysql connector on spyder via command line with this: 'conda install mysql-python'.

Does spyder require a different syntax to use mysql-connector? How can I use mysql-connector for spyder?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I used a different code syntax in spyder which finally worked. Here is the successful code in spyder python 2.7:
import MySQLdb
conn=MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='xxxxx',db='xxxxx')
mycursor=conn.cursor()

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of using MySQLdb likely is working just fine for you, but for clarification:

MySQLdb and MySQL.Connector are two different ports for MySQL and Python. The code in your question appears to be valid syntax for MySQL.Connector, which for Spyder is installed via

conda install mysql-connector-python

Answer (score 0):

use pip install mysql-connector-python in

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, run the `pip install mysql-connector` command in Spyder IPython Console(Where executions are done) and when execution is finished then restart kernel after that you can use `import mysql.connector`.